# How can I round a number in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, int

I want to round 1.7976 to 1.8. I've tried Math.round() and Math.float() but both give me 2 instead of what I want.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var number = 1.7976;
var rounded = Math.round( number * 10 ) / 10;
console.log(rounded);
```